# search array of strings in an enum and return true if available

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, enums

I have an enumeration:

```
    [Flags]
    public enum MyColours{
    Red = 1,
    Green = 2, 
    Blue = 4,
    Yellow = 8,
    Orange = 16,
    };
```

Now i have a list of strings:

```
    string[] colour = new string { "Red", "Orange", "Blue"};
```

I want to able to return true for the stirngs which match with enums.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?  What is the question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: `return true for the strings` - that's not clear at all. Do you want to pass in a *single* string and return *true* if it represents a value in the `enum`?

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear. I'm Newbie to programming. Here I would like to write a method which takes arguments as list of colours and would like to specifically know which colours  in the list matches the enums and place some flag like true or false for those specific colours.

Answer (score 4):

The question suks.

I think you want to see if a value in your enum matches a parameter, and returns true dependant on that parameter?

```
bool IsInsideEnum(string value) {
  foreach (var enumVal in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyColors)) 
    if(Enum.GetName(typeof(MyColors), enumVal) == value) 
      return true;
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your question is really vague. But i am assuming you mean something like this

```
if (colour[0] == Enum.GetName(typeof(MyColors), 1)) //"Red" == "Red"
{
   return true;
}
```

`Enum.GetName(typeof(MyColors), 1)` is what you are looking for

typeof(enumName) followed by enumIndex

Comment: This only goes into the if on the first loop

Comment: you assume he has a loop.  his question is vague AF. i supplied the code needed for him to proceed

Answer (score 1):

```
   List<string> colour = new List<String>{ "Red", "Orange", "Blue" };
   List<string> enumColors = Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyColours)).ToList();
   foreach (string s in enumColors)
   {
          if (colour.Exists(e => e == s))
              return true;
          else
              return false;

   }
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

use `Enum.GetName(Enum,int)` to get the string of an enumeration

Answer (score 0):

BETTER ANSWER - LESS VERBOSE:

```
var values = Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyColours)).ToList();

string[] colour = new string[] { "Red", "Orange", "Blue" };

List<string> colourList = colours.ToList();

ConatainsAllItems(values, colourList);

public static bool ContainsAllItems(List<T> a, List<T> b)
{
    return !b.Except(a).Any();
}
```

This should return true if they have matching values

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Enum.TryParse` method, something like this:

```
MyColours c;
from s in colour select new {Value = s, IsAvailable = Enum.TryParse(s, true, out c)}
```

Or you can do a `loop` and figure that out for each value in the array using that method.

Answer (score 0):

Quite direct, put `Enum.IsDefined` for that:

```
   string[] colour = new string[] { "Red", "Orange", "Blue", "White" };

   var result = colour
     .Select(c => Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyColours), c));
```

Test

```
  // True, True, True, False
  Console.Write(String.Join(", ", result));
```

Comment: This method is a little advanced. seeming the user doesn't know how to do it in the first place, linq selects should probably wait ... at least for a while

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
foreach(string s in colour)
       { 
           Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyColours)).Contains(s); 
       }
```